# Android - How to read Package Name in Application Class

Tags: android, android-activity

How to read Package Name in Application Class ? Is it possible.

I tried as below.

```
..... this.packagename;
Context context = getApplicationContext();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
```

Nothing works

Comment: where you put this code onCreate() ?

Comment: using Gradle? `String packageName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID;`

Comment: Please explain, completely and precisely, what "nothing works" means. What are your **exact symptoms**?

Comment: In Application class Constructor i need to read application package name.

Answer (score 2):

> In Application class Constructor i need to read application package name

Get rid of the `Application` constructor. You should not have one, just as you do not put a constructor on an `Activity`.

Your entry point in `Application` is `onCreate()`. After you chain to the superclass in `super.onCreate()`, `getPackageName()` should work. **It definitely will not work before then**, such as from the constructor you are erroneously creating.

As Blundell notes, if you using Android Studio or Gradle for Android, you are welcome to use `BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID` from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

put it in onCreate() in the Application class

Comment: I tried that too ... Not working

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myapp implements application{}

public class exeapp implements myapp {  }
```

Assume myapp is a custom application class from another.

By implements of myapp class in new application class is it possible to read package name in onCreate()